# Criar um novo banco de dados com usuário e senha Mysql diretamente pelo PHP

Tags: php, mysql

É possível criar um novo banco de dados com usuário e senha Mysql diretamente pelo script PHP? Pergunto porque estamos finalizando um sistema de cadastro onde cada cliente terá sua própria base de dados. Em caso positivo, teria como disponibilizar um exemplo? Entendo que para criar uma base de dados, posso usar:

```
mysqli_query($conexaoPrimaria,"CREATE DATABASE ".$banco." ");
```

Mas o usuário ( com todas as permissões ) e senha?

=====================

## RESPOSTA

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
mysqli_query($conexao,"CREATE USER 'novo_usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS 'senha_usuario'");
mysqli_query($conexao,"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'novo_usuario'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;");
mysqli_query($conexao,"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `novo_usuario`.* TO 'novo_usuario'@'localhost';");
mysqli_query($conexao,"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `novo_usuario\_localhost`.* TO 'novo_usuario'@'localhost';");
```

======================

Comment: Olá Bacco, sim, já havia visto esse post, porém para mim não serviu, pois é muito vago e sem exemplos conforme solicitei.

Comment: Quando houver pergunta similar a sua e não tiver resposta boa, você pode colocar pontos de reputaçao nela para atrair novas respostas. Duplicar a dúvida não é o caminho adequado nestes casos.

Comment: Certo, mas como faço isso? Ainda é possível receber respostas nesse post? Pois consegui resolver e gostaria de compartilhar.

Comment: Não, se tiver algo a acrescentar, seria o caso de adaptar para o post original "Criar usuário e banco de dados MySQL via PHP". Assim fica bom pra quem achar qualquer uma das duas questões, visto que a sua sempre servirá de índice para aquela. Seria bom se o @Darlei passasse a dele pra lá tambem.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é possível, mas uma coisa que fique claro, não inicie a sessão como root para fazer esses comandos.

Com isso em mente, um método semelhante a este pode funcionar.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', password);
mysql_query("CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';");
mysql_query("GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'username'@'localhost'");
mysql_close();
```

Se você tem um banco de dados dedicado para esses novos usuários como citou, você pode atribuí-lo facilmente.

Answer (score -2):

Para criar um usuário você não precisa colocar um campo para token , que seria a permissão, é necessário apenas gerar este token e colocar na sessão
ex:

`$_SESSION['token'] = $tokenGerado;`

a tabela de usuário você cria normalmente com seus dados